# Get Azure Block Blob properties while downloading it (BlockBlobClient.download)

Tags: javascript, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to download a blob from an azure blob storage container, using a SASToken url.

Code v1:

```
const blobClient = new BlobClient(urlWithSASToken, new AnonymousCredential()).getBlockBlobClient();
blobClient.download().then(async result => {
    const blob: Blob = await result.blobBody;
    console.log('Azure file metadata:');
    console.log(result.metadata);
    const fileName: string = result.metadata.filename;
    FileHelper.downloadBlobAs(blob, fileName);
});
```

code v2:

```
try {
    const blobClient = new BlobClient(urlWithSASToken, new AnonymousCredential()).getBlockBlobClient();
    const downloadResponse = await blobClient.download();
    const blob: Blob = await downloadResponse.blobBody;
    console.log('Azure file metadata:');
    console.log(downloadResponse.metadata);
    const fileName: string = downloadResponse.metadata.filename;
    FileHelper.downloadBlobAs(blob, fileName);
} catch (err: any) {}
```

The file is downloaded, but with "undefined" as name, as result.metadata seem to be empty. I looked at the XHR, and the metadata I'm looking for is there (as "x-ms-meta-filename"), but seem to not be available in the BlobDownloadResponseParsed.metadata object.

CORS are set by using an ARM template. Here is the relevant section:

```
"cors": {
    "corsRules": [{
        "allowedOrigins": [
            "[parameters('WebsiteURL')]"
        ],
        "allowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "GET"
        ],
        "maxAgeInSeconds": 0,
        "exposedHeaders": [
            "Access-Control-*"
        ],
        "allowedHeaders": [
            "content-type",
            "x-ms-blob-content-type",
            "x-ms-blob-type",
            "x-ms-client-request-id",
            "x-ms-meta-filename",
            "x-ms-version"
        ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use `async` inside a `then`. Consider either using `then` or `async/await` rather than mixing them together?

Comment: I use the `then` in order to more easily catch error (this is not the whole code, only the part relevant to my problem). I'm not a very experimented JS developer, my code isn't yet very clean ;).

Comment: I'm not trying to criticise or demand "clean code". It's that mixing async/then syntax tends to lead to confusion.

Comment: I added a new version using only `await` and a `try`/`catch`.

Comment: In your 2nd code sample, what gets printed here `console.log(downloadResponse.metadata);`? An empty object? Can you confirm if the metadata has been set properly on the blob?

Comment: Also, can you share your CORS settings especially `Exposed Headers`?

Comment: 1. Yes, the metadata is set in Azure and shows with no problem in the Azure Portal an on the XHR GET (and HEAD) requests.
2. I added the CORS section for my ARM template.

Comment: Please check my answer. HTH.

Comment: Ok, found the bug. I did not add the required headers to the "exposedHeaders" section. edit : posted this comment at the same time as yours. Yes, this worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially the problem is with your CORS settings (exposed headers). You're only exposing `Access-Control` related response headers and that's why you're not getting metadata back as `x-metadata-*` response headers are not exposed (blocked).

Please change `Exposed Headers` to allow all response headers by doing something like:

```
"exposedHeaders": [
    "*"
]
```

and you should see metadata populated.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the metadata for a Blob you need to explicitly get them. In JavaScript you can do so by calling the `getProperties()` function.

> Returns all user-defined metadata, standard HTTP properties, and system properties for the blob. It does not return the content of the blob.

More info: [BlobURL class - getProperties(Aborter, IBlobGetPropertiesOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/bloburl?view=azure-node-legacy#getProperties_Aborter__IBlobGetPropertiesOptions_)

Comment: Is there a way to get them from the GET request itself? Everything seem to be there, and like that I won't have to add the HEAD method to the CORS definition.

Comment: I tried this solution, metadatas are still empty.